# bitwise join two if's into one

Tags: c#, enums, bit-manipulation

I have this,

```
public enum Condition : uint // bitwise
{
    None = 0,
    NewLine = 1,
    Space = 2
}

Rule.Condition someCondition = Rule.Condition.Space | Rule.Condition.NewLine;
```

I'd like to convert this,

```
if ((Rule.Condition.Space & condition) == Rule.Condition.Space) return true;
if ((Rule.Condition.NewLine & condition) == Rule.Condition.NewLine) return true;
```

Into something like,

```
if((someCondition & condition) == someCondition) return true;
```

But it isn't working.  What am I forgetting?

Comment: I am not quite understand what you want. You can use Flag attribute to make sure life easier when there is a bitwise related conditions. Here is a good source for Flag Attribute http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/enum-flags-attribute

Comment: It is more complex than what I posted.  But if the 'previous' to the current check is a space or new line, then true.  Otherwise I have to check other things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if you're just wanting to test for none, then check for `> 0`. But, if you're looking for a less specific solution, something like this would combine the two and remove the `if` altogether:

```
return (int)(someCondition & (Condition.Space | Condition.NewLine)) > 0
```

Comment: Ok, thanks - I check for other things, so I need the if - thanks to you and sverre for getting back so quickly.

Comment: Gotcha. If you are using a similar test multiple times, you probably should do something like `var test = Condition.Space | Condition.NewLine`, then you can reuse it as `if ((someCondition & test) > 0)` wherever you need it. Also, consider using the `[Flags]` attribute on your enum, as it provides some built-in functionality for you.

Answer (score 3):

There is a special convenience method `HasFlag` in .NET4 expressly for this purpose:

```
if (condition.HasFlag(someCondition)) return true;
```

Here's the docs:

- [Enum.HasFlag Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx)

Comment: sweet - though I'm not using 4 yet :/

Answer (score 2):

`someCondition` has two bits set, one for `Rule.Condition.Space` and one for `Rule.Condition.NewLine`. `someCondition & condition` will have one bit set if `condition` is Space or NewLine, and be `0` otherwise.

You should test if the bitwise operation returns `0` instead of checking for equality with `someCondition`

```
if ((someCondition & condition) != 0) return true
```